# App crashing on loading native library for webRTC

Tags: android, android-ndk, webrtc, quickblox

My App is crashing when i add the native libraries in jniLibs, (i.e. libjingle_peerconnection_so.so ) for all architectures.

Following is stack trace extract that is causing restart crash of app.

```
W/System.err(11538): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.webrtc.DataChannel$Buffer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sample.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sample.app-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution, Proguard was interfering with my webrtc files. Added keep-files in proguard settings.

Answer (score 2):

This line solved my problem.
Add below line in the progaurd rule file.

```
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
```

Comment: this works! reference can be found here: https://github.com/RWebRTC/WebRTC-Android-Learn/blob/master/RAppRTC/app/proguard-rules.pro